# Insert row at a specific location in matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to add rows to a matrix at particular locations, where the locations are contained in a vector. The schema below shows the inputs and the expected outcome. I tried to use a "for" loop but couldn't make it work. Any suggestions help.

Source Matrix (6x3)

```
(1) 1   2   3
(2) 4   5   6
(3) 7   8   9
(4) 6   9   2
(5) 3   6   1
(6) 2   2   7
```

Vector of locations (indicates the row in the source matrix that will contain zeros)

```
[2, 5, 6]
```

Result Matrix(6+length.vector x 3)

```
(1) 1   2   3
(2*)0   0   0
(3) 4   5   6
(4) 7   8   9
(5*)0   0   0
(6*)0   0   0
(7) 6   9   2
(8) 3   6   1
(9) 2   2   7
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mat <- matrix(1:18,6)
vec <- c(2, 5, 6)

# New matrix 'new_mat' with all zeros, 
# No. of rows = original matrix rows + number new rows to be added
new_mat <- matrix(0,nrow=9,ncol=3)  

# 'new_mat' rows getting filled with `mat` values
new_mat[-vec,] <- mat   
new_mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    7   13
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    2    8   14
# [4,]    3    9   15
# [5,]    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    0
# [7,]    4   10   16
# [8,]    5   11   17
# [9,]    6   12   18
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach:

```
## inputs
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,6,9,2,3,6,1,2,2,7),ncol=3L,byrow=T);
i <- c(2L,5L,6L);

## solution
ris <- integer(nrow(m)+length(i)); ris[i] <- nrow(m)+1L; ris[-i] <- seq_len(nrow(m));
rbind(m,0)[ris,];
##       [,1] [,2] [,3]
##  [1,]    1    2    3
##  [2,]    0    0    0
##  [3,]    4    5    6
##  [4,]    7    8    9
##  [5,]    0    0    0
##  [6,]    0    0    0
##  [7,]    6    9    2
##  [8,]    3    6    1
##  [9,]    2    2    7
```

It works by first computing a vector of row indexes `ris`. The vector is first allocated to the required size, which is the number of rows in the original matrix `nrow(m)` plus the number of rows to be inserted, which is `length(i)`. Then the insertion indexes are assigned to an index just outside the number of rows in the original matrix `nrow(m)+1L`, and the non-insertion indexes are assigned to the sequence `seq_len(nrow(m))`. We can attain the required output by indexing with `ris` a composite matrix that consists of the original matrix row-bound with a row of zeroes (or whatever set of values is desired to be inserted at each insertion index).

Answer (score 1):

This one is similar to @bgoldst's answer, just a bit different.  It adds a row of zeros and then reorders the rows.  We start with a vector of `nrow(m) + 1` of length `nrow(m) + length(x)` (where `x` is the location vector) , and then replace the indices that are not in `x` with their respective original indices.

```
nr <- nrow(m)
rbind(m, 0)[replace(rep(nr + 1L, nr + length(x)), -x, seq_len(nr)), ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    4    5    6
# [4,]    7    8    9
# [5,]    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    0
# [7,]    6    9    2
# [8,]    3    6    1
# [9,]    2    2    7
```

**Data:**

```
m <- structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 7L), .Dim = c(6L, 3L))
x <- c(2, 5, 6)
```

Comment: After further review, this is really close to the other answer.  If anyone feels I should remove it please upvote this comment.  Second opinions always count.

Answer (score 1):

@SowmyaS.Manian's answer is good.

Let me expand it to address a slightly different situation.  The question identifies the *resulting* rows to create.  However, consider a case where the goal is to insert rows *prior* to `[2, 5, 6]`.  That is, the goal is to convert:

```
(1) 1   2   3
(2) 4   5   6
(3) 7   8   9
(4) 6   9   2
(5) 3   6   1
(6) 2   2   7
```

to

```
(1) 1   2   3
(2) 0   0   0
(3) 4   5   6
(4) 7   8   9
(5) 6   9   2
(6) 0   0   0
(7) 3   6   1
(8) 0   0   0
(9) 2   2   7
```

The noted solution still works, of course, but the issue is to identify the needed row numbers to use.  The trick is to add a vector from 0 to the number of rows to insert minus 1 to the indexes of the rows.  Consider:

```
vec     <- c(2, 5, 6)
vec     <- vec + 0:length(vec)
new_mat <- matrix(0, nrow=9, ncol=3)  
new_mat[-vec,] <- mat
```

This gives you what you would get if you highlighted rows 2, 5, and 6 in Excel and clicked `insert rows`.

Answer (score 0):

This must be too late, but I hope this reply would help anyone. Let the Source Matrix be an object A.

```
AA <- A[c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6), ]
AA[c(2,5,6), ] <- c(0,0,0)
```