# How to insert row in a (sparse) matrix efficiently?

Tags: r, performance, row, sparse-matrix

I have a huge sparse matrix and need to insert a row at a specific row index. I essentially applied the technique suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625471/insert-row-at-a-specific-location-in-matrix-using-r), but that's very inefficient since it copies the original matrix.

Here's the code in a nutshell, the scope is to generate `M2` efficiently (ideally, directly replacing `M`, so that `M2` is not even needed):

```
library(Matrix)

M  = as(cbind(1:4,1:4),"sparseMatrix") # original sparse matrix
M # view
v  = c(2,4) # row indices where new rows should be inserted
M2 = M # copy matrix to keep sparse class
for(i in 1:length(v)) M2 = rbind(M2,rep(0, ncol(M2))) # insert new rows at end
M2[-v,] = M # get each row in v 2 times ## <- THIS takes very long
M2[v,] = 0 # populate the newly inserted rows (e.g. here: 0)
M2 # view
```

Ideally I'm looking for a function such as `append` for vectors or `add_row` for a tibble.

EDIT: I notice that not only is the procedure above inefficient, it's also not what I'm looking for, because it adds rows at indices 2 and 4 of the *new* (resulting) matrix M2, while I am looking for adding rows at indices 2 and 4 of the *old* (initial) matrix, i.e. the end result as of now is:

```
[1,] 1 1
[2,] . .
[3,] 2 2
[4,] . .
[5,] 3 3
[6,] 4 4
```

i.e. rows were added at indices 2 and 4 of the new matrix. What I am looking for is:

```
[1,] 1 1
[2,] . .
[3,] 2 2
[4,] 3 3
[5,] . .
[6,] 4 4
```

i.e. new rows have been added before indices 2 and 4 of the old matrix. In his +1 answer @Ben Bolker correctly interpreted this as such. :)

Comment: You can't. Adding a row means reallocating new backing data arrays and copying the old data over. The same applies to adding new data points within a row.

Comment: Do you need the matrix to be in (default) "dgCMatrix" (compressed sparse-column) format or is "dgTMatrix" (triplet form) OK?  (If you don't know, it probably is ...)

Comment: @CJR, I'm not sure. Can't we manipulate the underlying arrays/indices?

Comment: @Ben Bolker: dgTMatrix is also ok to start with, since it can be converted to dgCMatrix afterwards. I only added tidyverse for the pipeline operator, admittedly overkill here :) I changed it now

Comment: @CJR, for a vector this works with append(), thought maybe there's something similar for matrices that I don't know of

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it applies to both dgC and dgT but I'm not 100%. You can't manipulate the underlying data cause the structures just aren't big enough to hold everything. The only option is two pass, where you figure out how much data you'll have, allocate the appropriate sized arrays, and then fill them in a second pass.

Comment: Appending stuff iteratively to vectors is also very slow. That's why apply is so much faster than looping.

Comment: @CJR, what do you think of my answer?  In a sparse matrix the underlying data structures are at best of order of (number of non-zero entries), at worst of order of (number of rows): not R*C.  My solution requires storage of order (number of added rows)*R.  Doing it in C++ (e.g. via `Rcpp`) would be a little easier because then you could iterate without a performance penalty

Comment: I now realize that the solution I wrote works equally well for `dgTMatrix` or `dgCMatrix` (and would in fact be **harder** for a compressed row format ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work reasonably efficiently: it manipulates the underlying row indices and dimensions of a matrix in sparse (`dgCMatrix` or `dgTMatrix`) format.

```
add_rows <- function(M,v) {
    oldind <- seq(dim(M)[1])-1L   ## all rows (0-indexed)
    ## new row indices: count how many rows are inserted before a given row
    ## (maybe a clearer/better/more efficient way to do this?)
    newind <- oldind + as.integer(rowSums(outer(oldind,v,">=")))
    ## modify dimensions
    M@Dim <- M@Dim + c(length(v),0L)
    ## modify row indices (1L accounts for 0 vs 1-indexing)
    M@i <- newind[M@i+1L]
    M
}
```

The part most likely to be a (memory/computation) bottleneck is the computation of the new row indices. I did this by constructing an index of *all* row numbers. The version below only does the `newind` computation for occupied rows, at the cost of additional calls to `unique()` and `match()`.

```r
add_rows_2 <- function(M,v) {
    oldind <- unique(M@i)
    ## new row indices
    newind <- oldind + as.integer(rowSums(outer(oldind,v,">=")))
    ## modify dimensions
    M@Dim <- M@Dim + c(length(v),0L)
    M@i <- newind[match(M@i,oldind)]
    M
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer!! I will implement this, check the efficiency and then mark this answer as best if no further questions arise. :) It may be worth noting that it always adds rows *after* the indices in v of the initial matrix. (Not that it's a problem, if before is needed, then `v-1` will do.)

Comment: Update: works very efficiently, essentially instant. As a side-note: `v + 0:(length(v)-1)` are the row indices of the newly inserted rows (zeroes) in the new (resulting) matrix, helpful for filling them in (e.g. with the mean of the row before and after to get interpolation).